# Plotting heatmap on QGIS using external CSV values rather than density of lat/long points

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, heat-map

I'm trying to plot a heatmap in QGIS.

The lat/long coordinates I have are arranged into 4 parallel lines (4 survey transects), with a third column in the CSV file comprising a value ranging from 1 to 49 (a count of the number of species per point).

I have managed to produce a map that simply plots these coordinate points on a basemap, and then apply a heatmap based on density of the points. These coordinates are however taken at regular intervals, and therefore the heatmap is pretty homogenous.

How therefore would I alter it to draw the heatmap based upon the third column of values?

Comment: You need to weight the points by the column which holds the values, it's right there in the symbology.

Comment: Easy as that. Wicked, thank you!

Comment: A similar question, see here for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367096/create-an-heatmap-based-off-of-a-numeric-attribute-in-a-point-feature-class/367108#367108