# Create an 'heatmap' based off of a numeric attribute in a point feature class

Tags: qgis, heat-map, inverse-distance-weighted, business

I have a shapefile with several points, each of which has a numeric attribute 'price'. I am trying to find areas that have the most potential revenue concentrated based off of the price in the feature class. How might I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What did you try?  What happened when you tried it?  Where are you stuck?  A good question should include detail about what you're trying to do, what you've tried or what you've researched in finding a solution, and the result.  Please [edit] your question to include as much information as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Select [heatmap as layer rendering style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=heatmap#heatmap-renderer) and set Weight points by to the attribute 'price'. Than play around with the values for radius and maximum value to get a nice looking heatmap.

On the picture, I duplicated the layer to include the points with their price-value in the label that you can see how the heatmap renders depending on the density of the points as well as the price-value:

[image]